# Are beta index, and average degree of a graph the same?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

It seems that a beta index, and an average degree of a graph are the same. They both are defined as the ratio of the number of edges to vertices of the graph. Please see definitions here: [beta index in graph](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://transportgeography.org/%3Fpage_id%3D6143&ved=2ahUKEwjGxY-m-I_sAhX1IbcAHd-tDR8QFjAVegQIDhAB&usg=AOvVaw0SP7V7oqTJF9gk0csIHZFO)

and [average vertex degree](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/social-media/1/steps/88735&ved=2ahUKEwjX9p61-o_sAhWHILcAHVe9BkwQFjABegQIBBAD&usg=AOvVaw0m9E_rWiPntPJ62ZCYOntp)

If both mean the same thing, what is the need of different nomenclatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average vertex degree is always exactly twice the beta index, because each edge connects two vertices. This is a version of the [handshaking lemma](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-handshaking-lemma).

For example, your link states that the beta index of a cycle is $1$, and every vertex of a cycle has degree $2$.

Comment: Is there known symbol or notation for representing average vertex degree of a graph $G$. I am thinking of a notation $Avgd(G)$ to mean the average vertex degree of $G$. Will it be feasible? Please suggest me.

Comment: I am not familiar with any specific notation for average degree. As long as you clearly spell it out what you mean ahead of time, I think you should be fine.

Comment: Ok. thanks....$#